# How to draw a GdkPixbuf using GTK3 and PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I have a small application that uses a `DrawingArea` to draw a simple map using `PyGObject` and `GTK3`.

I load a `Pixbuf` using

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size("logo.png", 25, 25)
```

and then try to draw it in the `DrawingArea`'s draw event signal

```
def draw(self, widget, context):
    window = widget.get_window()
    ctx = window.cairo_create()
    ctx.set_source_pixbuf(pixbuf, 0, 0)
```

but I get the error message

```
"AttributeError: 'cairo.Context' object has no attribute 'set_source_pixbuf'"
```

If I'm reading the [Gtk2 to Gtk3 migration guide](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html#id1280341) correctly, this should work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting something drawable back from get_window?

Comment: Yes, I get a `<gtk.gdk.X11Window object at 0xb71aab44 (GdkX11Window at 0x9db5aa0)>` object back, so the DrawingArea widget is realized. I seem to be at a loss of how drawing pixbufs in Gtk3 is supposed to work.

Comment: Since the accepted answer is _not to use a pixbuf_, and the real problem was not on how to draw a pixbuf can you change the question so that people (like me) coming here to find an answer on _how to really draw a GdkPixbuf using GTK3 and PyGObject_ do not step into this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new *draw* signal uses a callback that already passes the cairo context as a parameter, you don't need to do stuff like `window = widget.get_window()` like you did in PyGtk to get the cairo context while attending the *expose-event* signal. In PYGObject is simpler:

```
import cairo

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):

       (...)
        self.image = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('logo.png')
       (...)

    def draw(self, widget, context):
        if self.image is not None:
            context.set_source_surface(self.image, 0.0, 0.0)
            context.paint()
        else:
            print('Invalid image')
        return False
```

That is if you don't need the PixBuf, but if you need it for something else you have several options:

1. To have both objects in memory. If both are loaded from a PNG there should not be much problems other than the waste of memory.
2. Convert GdkPixbuf to PIL Image, then PIL Image to data array and then create a Cairo ImageSurface from that data array using create_for_data(). Yak :S I don't know better, sorry :S
3. Use **Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf()** proposed by hock. This seems to be the correct way to draw a Pixbuf in a ImageSurface, but it is totally unpythonic (and that's why I hate this Introspection stuff, all looks like C, like a bad C port).

If you choose the awful second option here is how:

```
import Image
import array
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

width = 25
height = 25
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size('logo.png', width, height)
pil_image = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (width, height), pixbuf.get_pixels())
byte_array = array.array('B', pil_image.tostring())
cairo_surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(byte_array, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height, width * 4)
```

Note that **create_for_data()** is [not yet available for Python3](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data), [only for Python2](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data).

Check also my answer on how to use a double buffer in PyGObject if this is what you're trying to achieve: [Drawing in PyGobject (python3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270795/drawing-in-pygobject-python3)

Kind regards

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a lot saner way of handling graphics in GTK3 than my various efforts ;)

Comment: +1 "but it is totally unpythonic (and that's why I hate this Introspection stuff, all looks like C, like a bad C port)."

Comment: Update create_for_data is now available, the current docs are here https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to do the job:

```
def draw(self, widget, context):
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(context, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
    context.paint()
```

One question still remains: Is this the preferred way of doing things?

Comment: my program generates "segmentation faults" after executing ``cairo_set_source_pixbuf`` any help ?

Comment: In Gtk doc they say „be careful, this function is not from cairo ...”. I should -1 the answer above this one, but seem's more constructive to +1 this one. Gtk3 is a diferent way of things, it use cairo and give back the handler to surface, so don't act like it is an external tool: there are where the drawings happends.

Comment: @AkashShende - I am also getting a segmentation fault using `.cairo_get_source_pixbuf`, did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @nluigi I gave up on Pixbuf and used `Cairo_Surface` and used method `cairo_set_source_surface` to set image. Check this https://github.com/akash0x53/i3lock/commit/f0acf46ef9738fb70cc89f9c4e43b527c3fb37d2

Comment: @AkashShende - thx, it turned out not to be a problen with `.cairo_set_source_pixbuf` for me but the call to `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data` call i was doing. [Changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327001/segmentation-fault-while-drawing-frame-from-webcam-to-drawablearea-in-pygtk3) to `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes` fixed it for me.