# Cannot get pygobject to use a drawing area

Tags: python, pygobject

Generally, I have been successful in using the Gtk3 system: Windows, boxes, grids, signal handlers etc.  But, no matter what I try I cannot get a DrawingArea widget to work.  I suspect something is wrong with my set-up but do not know how to check.  Here is a bare-bones example that really should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
class MyExample(object): 
  def __init__(self, user_data=None): 
    window = Gtk.Window() 
    window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit) 
    drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea() 
    drawing_area.set_size_request(300,300) 
    drawing_area.connect('draw',self.expose) 
    window.add(drawing_area) 
    window.show_all()  
  def expose(self,widget,cr,data): 
    print ("self_exposed") 
# === 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = MyExample() 
    Gtk.main()
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Exception TypeError: TypeError("Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct
'cairo.Context'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py'>
ignored
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 3.2.  I suspect something is wrong with my install but what? I have tried re-installing python-gi-cairo.

Thanks for any ideas,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

Check my answer here:

[Drawing in PyGobject (python3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270795/drawing-in-pygobject-python3/10541984#10541984)

You need to install **python3-gi-cairo** package.

Comment: Thanks Havok.  It works with 2.7 as you say.  I installed the python3-cairo package but that did not help it run in 3.2.  If I find a solution I will post it.

Comment: There is also other minor problems when using Cairo for Python 3.x, check also this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10547095/439494 just to give you more ideas.

Comment: Gabriel Brunne give the solution, you need to install **python3-gi-cairo** to make the example code to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the "draw" signal never gets sent when using Gtk+ 3 and Python 3. I cant figure it out but it really puts a damper on my project and is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar problems, having tried the python3-cairo package to no positive results.

However, installing the **python3-gi-cairo** package solved it for me.

In my case, under Ubuntu 12.04, ***$ sudo apt-get install python3-gi-cairo***
in a terminal did the trick, getting me rid of the annoying "Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Context'" messages.

It'll problably also work on other Ubuntu versions, maybe on Debian as well...

Other distros may have similar packages, but I can't provide much help on this.

Hope I've been of help.

Comment: Thanks, that changed everything, I updated the solution on the other question.