# Segmentation fault while drawing frame from webcam to DrawableArea in pygtk3

Tags: python, opencv, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

As title suggests I am reading frames from my webcam (using openCV, i want to do some follow up feature detection with it) and want to write the result to a pyGTK3 DrawableArea widget. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287230/1271603) answer, which i will quote for convenience:

> The following seems to do the job:

```
def draw(self, widget, context):
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(context, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
    context.paint()
```

> One question still remains: Is this the preferred way of doing things?

So i am now using:

```
def _on_drawablearea_draw(self, canvas, context):
    frame = self.stream.read()
    self.pixbuf = self._frame2pixbuf(frame)
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(context, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
    context.paint()

def _frame2pixbuf(self, frame):
    height, width, rgb_stride = frame.shape
    frame_to_list = frame.flatten() # must become list
    return GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(frame_to_list,
                                          GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
                                          False, 8, 
                                          width, height, rgb_stride * width)
```

`frame` is a numpy array of shape `(m,n,3)`.

Unfortunately, I get a `segmentation fault` at the statement:

```
Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(context, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
```

This apparantly happened to more members as seen in the comments to the above quoted answer, however no solution was provided and a quick google search yields no results.

**Update 1:** Loading pixbuf from file is working as expected, i.e.

```
def _image2pixbuf(self):
    filename = 'some_test_image.jpg'
    return GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(filename)
```

with the same call to `_on_drawablearea_draw` except for the change to `._image2pixbuf` renders `some_test_image.jpg` perfectly in the DrawableArea widget.

**Update 2:** Converting to bytes and creating the pixbuf from bytes works for me, i.e.

```
def _frame2pixbuf(self, frame):
    height, width, rgb_stride = frame.shape
    frame_in_bytes = GLib.Bytes.new(frame.tobytes())
    return GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes(frame_in_bytes,
                                          GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
                                          False, 8, 
                                          width, height, rgb_stride * width)
```

but it adds an 'unnecessary' (?) additional step of converting the frame data to bytes.

**Questions**:

1. How do i fix this segmentation fault in the case of `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data`? It seems to me now that the arguments to the function are badly chosen.
2. Furthermore, as the above quoted answer also asks: is this the preferred way of writing a frame from a webcam to a DrawableArea widget?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the issue is that [new_from_data()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-data) does not make a copy of the image data that you pass to it, it uses it directly and in your case the image data is contained in the `frame_in_bytes` variable which is local to the `_frame2pixbuf` function. Thus that image data is likely freed and is no longer valid once you're out of the `_frame2pixbuf` function scope.

This is not the case when you use the `new_from_file` function which allocates the image memory itself; nor in the case of `new_from_bytes` because you create a new Bytes object on the heap which does not get freed when you leave the function scope.

To use `new_from_data()`, you would have to make sure that your image data does not become invalid before `Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf()` is called. I think one way to do that would be to put the contents of your `_frame2pixbuf` function into your `_on_drawablearea_draw` function so that the `frame_in_bytes` var remains valid in that context.